# Proving non-compactness of a manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, compactness

I have been trying to solve the following problem:
Let $M \subset \mathbb R^3$ be the set of points $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3$ at which $xy + xz + yz = 1.$ Prove that $M$ is a $2$-dimensional manifold. Prove that $M$ is not compact.

I have so far proven that $M$ is a $2$-dimensional manifold by checking for singularities, but am unsure how to prove that $M$ is compact. Is it sufficient to prove that $M$ is unbounded because $(x,y,z)$ is unbounded (at least as far as I can see) and hence not compact? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a set is compact iff is bounded and closed, it is sufficient to prove that $M$ is not bounded.

Comment: @Onil90 thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $x_n = n$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{2n}$. Then
$$xy + xz + yz = \frac{1}{2} + z\frac{2n^2+1}{2n},$$
so that by taking $z_n=\frac{n}{2n^2+1}$, the points $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ are on the manifold. This shows that the manifold is not bounded (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$), and thus not compact.

Answer (score 0):

The set $z=0, xy = 1$ is the familar hyperbola in the $x$-$y$ plane. This hyperbola is unbounded, and is contained in $M.$ Therefore $M$ is unbounded, hence is not compact.